# Fragments, how to receive feedback?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a problem. According to the drawing, I have an activity that has three fragments, each fragment has its recycleview with the items to choose from, so far so good.
My goal: when I click on an item, it opens another activity, legending it with a variable, so far so good.

When I press the back button, I leave the second activity and go back to the first with the variable, the problem is when I return to the first activity, I tried to trigger a function that analyzes the variable within **onResume ()**, but this function it doesn't work, **I repeat**, it doesn't work with fragments. **What return function works on fragments? Is there another simple alternative?**

[See the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ov04t.png)

Answer (score 0):

Start your child Activity for result using `startActivityForResult()` and then in your child Activity set the result, after you have collected your data, using `setResult()` and manually finish your child Activity using `finish()`. Then in the Fragment class again, override `onActivityResult()` to receive the data set in your child Activity.

Refer to this guide for more in depth information: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.